# Getting bar chart with text formatting in jfreechart library

Tags: java, jfreechart

Im trying to implement jfreechart in my application i've referred some examples in [jfree](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/gjdoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/) 
 website. But i need a chart like [google's column chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)
. How can i get this type of chart in jfreecharts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to get the similar chart in jfreecharts

```
String Male1 = "First";
String Male2 = "sec";
String Female1 = "Category 1";
String Female2 = "Category 2";
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
dataset.addValue(10, Male1, Female1);
dataset.addValue(12, Male1, Female2);
dataset.addValue(22, Male2, Female1);
dataset.addValue(50, Male2, Female2);
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
     "Bar Chart Demo", "Category", "Score", dataset,
     PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
BarRenderer br = new BarRenderer();
br.setItemMargin(0.0);
chart.getCategoryPlot().setRenderer(br);
try {
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("E:\\jfreeBarchart.png"), chart, 500, 500);
    System.out.println("=====chart=====");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```